# Jquery prevent next events to bubble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple div and checkbox inside. Both elements are binded with onClick event. First is triggered on the inner element so checkbox , and then on the div. My question is: is this possible to stop any other events on DOM after rising first event untill next click ? other words can I stop in checkbox onClick to trigger event from div?

```
<div onclick="divOnClic(this);" style="width: 200px; height: 200px ; background-color: red">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxOnClick(this);"/>
</div>

function divOnClic(e) {
        alert('z diva');
    }

    function checkboxOnClick(e) {

        alert('z checka');
        e.preventDefault();

    }
```

here is live example http://jsfiddle.net/QK43u/1/

Comment: Do you want trigger checkboxOnClick but not divOnClic?

Comment: @jaapaurelio yes, this what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would solve your problem:

```
<div onclick="divOnClic(event);" style="width: 200px; height: 200px ; background-color: red">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxOnClick(event);"/>
    </div>

    function divOnClic(e) {
            alert('z diva');
        }

        function checkboxOnClick(e) {

            alert('z checka');
            e.stopPropagation()

        }
```

Comment: i still have both events triggered

Comment: have u got `jquery` library loaded on the page?

Comment: no, I just added to my post sample from JSFiddle and try your self that this solution will only stop current event , but not the parent, this example shows that div onClick is triggered anyhow.

Comment: its working for me here. here is the link http://jsbin.com/hajaboge/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: true, you r right, my problem was that I passed this insteda of event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: can you show me where ? I tried and it didn't worked.

Comment: @AshleyMedway True, the answerer should include why they should be using this and an example tbh.

Comment: @null no, this will stop current event from bubling, but not any others.

Comment: @null I just added JSFiddle example , please take a look.

Comment: @null seems you are correct , so you see , this should be aplied not to parameter but to event, please create answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault() method prevents the default event to be executed. It does not prevent bubbling. You need to use the stopPropagation() method.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click',divOnClick);
$('#myCheckBox').on('click',checkboxOnClick);

function divOnClick(e) {
  alert('div got clicked');
}
function checkboxOnClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert(e.isPropagationStopped());
 }
```

Note: I advice against using inline styles or inline event handlers.
See here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lged/7/

Note: Event bubbling is from the inner element and propagated to the outer element. There is no need to this for the div. Capturing is the other way around the div will propagate its event up the tree. There we do not stop the event from propagating.

Comment: NO, this will also stop checkbox event but not from div.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `event` inside your function call.
And use `stopPropagation()` to prevent propagation to the parent element.

```
<div onclick="divOnClic(event);" style="width: 200px; height: 200px ; background-color: red">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxOnClick(event);"/>
</div>

<script>
    function divOnClic(e) {
            alert('z diva');
        }

    function checkboxOnClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        alert('z checka');
    }
</script>
```